# 'Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface' not found

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron, cpanel

I'm trying to use `cpanel` `cron-job` to run a `PHP` script to automatically download email attachment and send some file via amazon web service. but, I'm getting this error instead :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface' not found in 
/home/admin/public_html/main/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Request.php on line 13
```

it works absolutely fine when I run the script in my local machine. it only happens in `cpanel`.

I've no idea how to solve this error. I've tried to google it but couldn't find any answer, and honestly speaking, I don't even know what's causes this error. can anyone help?

Comment: Have you installed composer/shipped up the vendor folder? What version of PHP, what script are you trying to run? Lots of questions... not really valid for SO

Comment: @Farkie hi farkie, thanks for answering. as i said before, i don't even know what causes the error. my php version is 5.5.37. my script is just a simple script. i use php imap to retrieve email and download its attachment, and send some file using amazon-ses. that's all. and no, i don't have composer/shipped up in the vendor folder